# Glusterd, One of the bricks contain the other

Tags: terminal

When configuring Glusterd I get the following error

'One of the bricks contain the other'

When executing the command

```
gluster volume create slitaz-volume replica 2 
192.168.56.101:/mnt/data 192.168.56.102:/mnt/data
```

I found something to fix it with getfattr and setfattr but when executing the command setfattr it answers with 'No such attribute'

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the uuids of each of the gluster are different. Look at /var/lib/glusterd/glusterd.info for the UUID. If they are the same gluster won't work. Stop the service, delete that file and restart glusterd again. That will fix your issue.

Comment: Deleted that file. And restarted. But Glusterd failed to start already. Any suggestion please?